# Who are all these connections showing up in the command prompt?

Tags: command-line, internet

I ran `netstat -no` and all these addresses came up:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kwnfz.png]

I had just restarted my computer and nothing was even running except for the command prompt. I didn't even have a browser open and I keep my computer very clean and organized.

Do I have a virus? What's with all the active connections?

(Windows 7 64-Bit)

Comment: Note that `TIME_WAIT` is *not* "active"; it's the [remains of a closed connection](http://www.unixguide.net/network/socketfaq/2.7.shtml). Having many of these is normal when browsing the web.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Picking one of the more common addresses at random (I chose `72.14.204.120`) and putting it into a web browser appears to go straight to Google so I would have to say that the `72.14.204.XXX` address range is pointing at Google and is most likely a result of the Google+ integration that is becoming more prevalent in every web page you visit.  It seems that google want to keep a close eye on what you do these days and so their connections are ongoing rather than fleeting...

That pretty much rules out about 2/3rds of your list, after that the number of connections looks normal for a web browser just generally "doing it's thing"

If you're curious then there is a neat tool [Whois by IP Address](http://tools.whois.net/whoisbyip/) which can tell you who onws a particular IP address range.

For example

```
96.6.172.20    -> Akamai Technologies, Inc (Webapp and download accelerators)
(same for most of the 96.16 - 96.17 range)  
Akamai Technologies, Inc. AKAMAI-200710 (NET-96-16-0-0-1) 96.16.0.0 - 96.17.255.255

74.125.226.140 -> Google (again)
Google Inc. GOOGLE (NET-74-125-0-0-1) 74.125.0.0 - 74.125.255.255

65.55.11.254   -> Microsoft (probably Windows Update)
Microsoft Corp MICROSOFT-1BLK (NET-65-52-0-0-1) 65.52.0.0 - 65.55.255.255
```

Take out those key players and all you are left with is a few general IP addresses for websites and stuff.

While having a bunch of connections like that running is vaguely odd, they are not uncommon these days with always-on internet as most people will not notice them and companies can get away with it.

I very much doubt you have a virus as the large proportion of connections are to reputable companies.

Answer (score 1):

Try `netstat -b` from an elevated command prompt instead and it will tell you which programs are responsible for the connections.

Whilst possible, it is unlikely that a virus (or other malware) is responsible.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old..but answering anyway.  There is a better way than Netstat to watch and decode the traffic.

1. Install Wireshark and winpcap
2. Go to this link and follow the instruction to enable Geolocation from Maximind Geodata files (http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/)
   that Wireshark can use.

https://wiki.wireshark.org/HowToUseGeoIP

3. Start Wireshark the moment you boot the PC up, and plug in the cable AFTER you have WS running. Makes SURE NOT to open a browser during this capture.
4. Start the capture with the geodata files configured in Wireshark, you can actually go the the frame data, right click the geo source and ASN number and make them "columns". Also, selecting destinations in your local network that you dont want to see in the filter by right clicking and choose "not follow" And "...not follow" and...etc. Until most of your local traffic is ignored.

Now, you can see exactly when the packet was initiated and to where and who is responding. Not only the ASN (BGP assigned number) but also the country.  You can even click on the packet and "follow stream" to read the data which sometimes shows readable text like HTTP Get requests, etc.

The best way to capture this fully is to get a hub from ebay or amazon used that is a true hub (not a switch) like an old Netgear 10/100, and connect it between your router and your PC (disable wifi of course).

When reading the data in Wires hark I have noticed that companies like Avast, and Microsoft not only have servers in other locations besides the US, but they also use Akamai as DDOS and Web Access Firewall (WAF) protection. Also for Web caching and speed efficiency techniques. Akamai is on 1/3 of the worlds cloud server coverage.

I found the chatty MS stuff very concerning.  So I downloaded some Win10 stop spying apps that helped a lot. Total silence.  Now all I see is Russia and China hunting around, but my PC ignores them like it is supposed to.

Hope this helps anyone reading this in August 2016 :-)

I could not post more than two links due to my newbie rep...so I commented below.

Comment: I used a couple different tools to shut MS up.

http://www.ghacks.net/2015/08/14/comparison-of-windows-10-privacy-tools/

http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/windows_10_tracking_disable_tool.html

WARNING, use at your own risk.  They didn't stop my Windows updates, but I guarantee nothing for you.  Make sure not to install any junk toolbars or apps if they have any (they didn't when I installed them), by choosing custom/advanced install ALWAYS. Read what you are agreeing to. Sometimes you can disagree with pre-messages and still install software. Companies are getting crafty.

Comment: Also, here is a real hub used for $20 bucks. 

https://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B00000J4LQ/ref=dp_olp_used?ie=UTF8&condition=used